# How can I determine/calculate a circumcenter with 3 points

Tags: scripting, add-on, geometry, 3d-cursor

I wanted to calculate the circumcenter of an object (for example of an cylinder).

For this purpose I use Z-mode to see the grid of an object and mark three points that are on the same circle. After this I calculate the circumcenter on paper and set my 3D cursor to those values.

Is there an addon/widget/plugin/script that I can add to Blender to archive the same without the hassle of manually calculating or can Blender do that by itself?

**The main goal I have is to get the midpoint of a circle object in Blender.** If the calculation with 3 points is unneeded and over complicating things tell me so please.

Furthermore sadly I do not find calculators online who support 3D vectors for this calculation. So If you can link me a calculator for tempory usage would be great too.

Comment: If you only want the midpoint, you could also calculate the center by the object's bounding box (the dimensions of an object) or is this not accurate enough in your case?

Comment: No absolutely not. The circle is not even near the center of the entire object. But I will keep it in my mind if I cross an circle only/center object, thanks!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I have written [such a tool](https://github.com/zeffii/Blender_CAD_utils#ccen-circle-centers), it creates a grease-pencil representation of the reconstructed circle if you can select 3 vertices of an incomplete circle. It also allows you to change the number of vertices of the new representation.

You can easily convert from grease pencil to mesh

[6 mb example image](https://cloud.githubusercontent.com/assets/619340/7046217/94813136-de04-11e4-9ef8-471b5eecb62f.gif)

Comment: Tremendous work you did there! Could you tell me how to select multiple vertices too? Thanks in advance, you saved my week!

Comment: I do not have those points/vertices. My circle is one continuous orange line. Maybe because my object was an import from an stl file.

Comment: well, if you imported it it's probably a mesh, maybe a very finely divided mesh, or is it a Curve Object? I thought STL was only triangles.

Comment: place your imported object in Edit Mode then you can select vertices

Comment: Oh I found it. I was not in Edit mode!

Comment: any feedback issues about the addon / operator should happen on github, while it works for my needs I am open to ideas. Remember the code is Free and Open source you can modify it to your own specifications if I don't want to implement ideas :)

Comment: @zeffii: Nice add-on! Exactly what I needed. Is there a way to output the 3dcursor location for each CCEN operation to a list? Ie, I need to find the centre for many groups of 3vertices.

Answer (score 4):

I cobbled together some python which computes the center of the circle through the 3 selected vertices of a mesh and assigns the 3D cursor to that location.

http://web.purplefrog.com/~thoth/blender/python-cookbook/compute-circle-center.html

You can paste that code into a blender Text Editor window and Run Script.  Here is a copy of the code in-line:

```
import bpy
import bmesh
from mathutils import *

def replace_col(M, i, C):
    for r in range(len(M)):
        M[r][i] = C[r]

def compute_circle_center_(B, C, N):

    m_d = Matrix( [
        B,C,N
    ])

    col = [B.dot(B)*0.5,
    C.dot(C)*0.5,
    0]

    m_x = m_d.copy()
    replace_col(m_x, 0, col)

    m_y = m_d.copy()
    replace_col(m_y, 1, col)

    m_z = m_d.copy()
    replace_col(m_z, 2, col)

    m_d_d = m_d.determinant()

    x = m_x.determinant() / m_d_d
    y = m_y.determinant() / m_d_d
    z = m_z.determinant() / m_d_d

    #print(m_d)
    #print(m_x)
    #print(m_y)
    #print(m_z)

    return Vector([x,y,z])

def compute_circle_center(A,B,C):
    #print ("%r\t %r\t %r"%(A,B,C))
    B_ = B-A
    C_ = C-A
    N = B_.cross(C_)
    #print ("%r\t %r\t %r"%(B_,C_, N))

    return A+compute_circle_center_(B_, C_, N)

def space_3d():
    for area in bpy.context.screen.areas:
        for space in area.spaces:
            if space.type=='VIEW_3D':
                return space
    raise AssertionError("could not find any editor space of type VIEW_3D")

def mission():
    obj = bpy.context.active_object
    verts=[]
    if bpy.context.mode == 'EDIT_MESH':
        bm = bmesh.from_edit_mesh(obj.data)
        for v in bm.verts:
            if v.select:
                verts.append(obj.matrix_world * v.co)
    else:
        for v in obj.data.vertices:
            if v.select:
                verts.append(obj.matrix_world * v.co)
    if len(verts) != 3:
        raise AssertionError("You must select exactly 3 vertices from the mesh, not %d"%len(verts))

    space_3d().cursor_location = compute_circle_center(verts[0], verts[1], verts[2])

#
#
#

mission()
```